# How to create a filmstrip of moving images beneath a slideshow using jQuery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a filmstrip of thumbnails to go with the slideshow that's on my website. They're supposed to move to the left every time the image in the slideshow changes; the leftmost one shrinks to a width of 0px; and a new one emerges from the right. Currently, however, the images will move to the left fine, but they don't cycle around, they simply keep moving off the page. A new one does appear at the end of the line.  The code I currently have is

```
    function slideImage() {
        var $pic1 = $('#pic1');
        var $pic8 = $('#pic8');

        if (i <= numImages - 8) {
            name8 = name1 + getString(i + 7) + name2;
        }
        else if (i <= numImages) {
            name8 = name1 + getString((i - numImages) + 7) + name2;
        }
        else {
            i = 1;
            name8 = name1 + getString(i + 8) + name2;
        }

        $pic1.animate({ width: "0px", padding: "0px" }, 1000, function () {
            $pic1.attr("id", "pic8")
                .attr("src", name8);
        });
        $pic8.animate({ width: "75px", padding: "5px"}, 1000, function () {
            $("#pic2").attr("id", "pic1");
            $("#pic3").attr("id", "pic2");
            $("#pic4").attr("id", "pic3");
            $("#pic5").attr("id", "pic4");
            $("#pic6").attr("id", "pic5");
            $("#pic7").attr("id", "pic6");
            $pic8.attr("id", "pic7");
        });
        $(".im").not("#pic8").animate({ left: "-=85px" }, 1000);
    }
```

I call this function every time I call the function that changes the image in the actual slideshow. I have a list of images with IDs pic1 to pic8, all absolutely positioned within a div. The source of the images is ..\photos\pic_.jpg, with _ being replaced by a three digit number from 1 to the number of images in the folder.  I'm really new to javascript and jquery, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks!